# Skipping an element of a list - Python

Tags: python

I have two json files that I open with Python. I want to do something such that if one condition isn't satisfied I can skip the current element and move on to the next one. My code looks something like the following:

```
t_a = first json file
t = second json file
for token in t_a
    if token in t
     #do something
    if token not in t
     #skip the current token and move on to the next one
```

My problem comes in with the last step. I'm new to python and I'm not sure how to skip the current element

Comment: [`continue`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement?

Comment: You need to load the two files into memory as well. Since you are new to code, I would suggest that you should post the whole code here. Also, look at the continue statement as @thefourtheye suggested.

Comment: so something along the lines of token = test_list.skip() continue?

Comment: Just get rid of the second `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`continue`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
t_a = first json file
t = second json file
for token in t_a
    if token in t:
     #do something
    else:
     #skip the current token and move on to the next one
        continue
    #do something else here
```